# C++ CLI equivalent of Intersect and Except

Tags: c#, c++-cli

For the following two lines of codes of C#, what would be equivalent in C++ CLI?
xList and yList is a generic List and can be of type int or double.

Do I need to implement something from scratch using some sorting algorithm and so on?

```
var newList = xList.Except(yList);
var new2List = xList.Intersect(yList);
```

Comment: Never used c++ (nor c++/cli), but aren't you supposed to be able to use Linq since you are running on .NET?

Comment: Take a look at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection and http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference.